# prove there exists $h/k$ so that $|r-h/k| \leq 1/(k(n+1))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

> Prove that for any real number $r$ and any positive integer n, there exists a rational number $h/k$ with $\gcd(h,k)=1$ so that $|r-h/k| \leq 1/(k(n+1))$ and $1\leq k\leq n.$

Among the real numbers $0,\langle r\rangle, \langle 2r\rangle,\cdots \langle (n+1)r\rangle$, two of them must lie in an interval of the form $[i/(n+1), (i+1)/(n+1))$ for some $i<n+1$. Also, $\langle a\rangle = a-\lfloor a\rfloor$ for any real number a by definition, and one can use this to get integers $h$ and $k$ satisfying $|kr-h|\leq 1/(n+1)$. But $k$ might be $n+1$ and I'm not sure how to eliminate that case.

Comment: Probably it should be "Prove that for any real number $r$ **and any integer $n$**", i.e. it lacks a $\forall n$?

Comment: [Yann Bugeaud, *Approximation by Algebraic Numbers*, p. 2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=iAg8FL5jKSgC&pg=PA2)